# Python find the index of a line of interest in a text file

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am writing a code that takes a file text as an input and it does the following:
It searches for a specific line I am interested (in this case `'InChIKey=HCZNPUHZYPPINM-AWEZNQCLSA-M'`) and it returns the index + 1 of the line that comes before my line of interest and that contains this character `'//'`

Here is my code

```
file_info = open('compounds.dat', 'r')
data = {}
line_index = 0
unique_line_index = 0
for line in file_info: 
    if '//' in line:
        #extract line index for lines that contain //
        line_index = [x for x in range(len(content)) if "//" in content[x]]

    elif 'InChIKey=HCZNPUHZYPPINM-AWEZNQCLSA-M' in line:
        # return index of line after //
        unique_line_index = line_index + 1
```

But I get the following error: `can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`.

Comment: Hi ,can you share compounds.dat and expected result ?

Comment: You turn `line_index` into a list when you encounter `'//'`, then you do `line_index + 1`. The error message could not be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

```
line_index = [x for x in range(len(content)) if "//" in content[x]]
```

Although You defined `line_index` as `int`, You overwrite it with this list, thus error message that You can't concatenate `int` to `list`.

*Update:*

For getting indexes of lines containing `//` use following:

```
file_info = open('compounds.dat', 'r')

special_line_indexes = []
unique_line_index = 0

for i, line in enumerate(file_info.readlines()): 
    if '//' in line:
        #extract line index for lines that contain //
        special_line_indexes.append(i + 1)

    elif 'InChIKey=HCZNPUHZYPPINM-AWEZNQCLSA-M' in line:
        # return index of line after //
        unique_line_index = i + 1
```

Comment: How can I obtain the index of the lines containing // without using this list?

Comment: Problem with this code is that unique_line_index is returning the index of the line after 'InChIKey=HCZNPUHZYPPINM-AWEZNQCLSA-M', while I want the index of the line after '//'

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: By running your code into my text file, I get the index 241, which corresponds to the line 'InChIKey=HCZNPUHZYPPINM-AWEZNQCLSA-M' +1. While what I want to get is the line 235, that is the line '//' + 1

Comment: Have You tried to print contents of `special_line_indexes`?

Comment: If I print special_line_indexes I get the last line of my file + 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156980/discussion-between-fejs-and-smvpfm).